# Prove $P(\sum_nX_n\text{ converges})=P(\sum_nX_n\mathbb{I}_{\{|X_n|\leq c_n\}}\text{ converges})$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

$\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of random variables,$\{c_n\}$ is a sequence of positive numbers,$\sum\limits_{n}P(|X_n|> c_n)<\infty$,prove $P(\sum_nX_n\text{ converges})=P(\sum_nX_n\mathbb{I}_{\{|X_n|\leq c_n\}}\text{ converges})$

Here are my attempts.From $\sum\limits_{n}P(|X_n|> c_n)<\infty$ we get $\lim_nP(|X_n|> c_n)=0$,also $P(\sum_nX_n\mathbb{I}_{\{|X_n|\leq c_n\}}\text{ converges})=P(\lim\limits_n\sum\limits_{k\geq n}X_k\mathbb{I}_{\{|X_k|\leq c_k\}}\text{ converges})$,and when $n$ is large enough,$P(|X_k|>c_k)=0$,and the proposition seems right,but I don't know how to show that in a rigorous way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $A = \{ \omega: |X_n| > c  \text{ for an infinite number of }  n\} = \cap_{N = 1}^{\infty} \cup_{n = N}^{\infty} \{ |X_n| > c\}$.

By  Borel–Cantelli lemma $P(A) = 0$.

For any $ \omega \notin A$ there is only finite number of $n$ such that $X_n \ne X_nI_{|X_n| > c}$. Hence for any $ \omega \notin A$ series $\sum_n X_n $ and $\sum_n X_nI_{|X_n| > c}$ converges (or diverges) simultaneously.
So $$P( (\Omega \backslash A ) \cap \{   \sum_n X_n < \infty \}) = P( (\Omega \backslash A ) \cap \{   \sum_n X_nI_{|X_n| > c} < \infty \}).$$
Since $P(\Omega \backslash A ) = 1$ the statement is proved.

Comment: Do you mean '...there is only a finite number of $n$ s.t. $X_n \neq X_nI_{|X_n|\leq c_n}$'?

Comment: Would make sense, looks good otherwise